# Retirar nomes duplicados por aproximação VBA

Tags: vba

Boa tarde!

Existe algum tipo de código para encontrar/retirar as duplicidades por aproximação? Estou tentando limpar uma base muito grande, porém os nomes que foram inseridos possuem erros de digitação ou letras com a mesma fonética.

Por exemplo: Luiz Carlos Silva ou Luis Carlos Silva

Obrigado!

Comment: Você possui alguma base de dados com os nomes considerados corretos?

Comment: Boa tarde! não tenho, esta base é extraída de um sistema de atendimento, os operadores digitam os dados dos atendidos, porém trabalhamos com população de rua ou com altas vulnerabilidades, então não é possível exigir nenhuma foram de documentação, o que tem acarretado num número gigantesco de duplicidades.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1a Opção - Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel

Você pode usar o [Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011) ou criar a própria lógica Fuzzy num programa. Procure por Procura Difusa ou em inglês *fuzzy search/lookup*.

> O Fuzzy Lookup Add-in para Excel foi desenvolvido pela Microsoft Research e uma correspondência difusa de dados de texto no Microsoft Excel. Ele pode ser usado para identificar linhas de duplicatas difusas dentro de uma única tabela ou para junções confusas em filas semelhantes entre duas tabelas diferentes. A correspondência é robusta para uma grande variedade de erros, incluindo erros ortográficos, abreviaturas, sinônimos e dados adicionados / ausentes. Por exemplo, pode detectar que as linhas "Mr. Andrew Hill", "Hill, Andrew R." e "Andy Hill" se referem à mesma entidade subjacente, retornando à pontuação de similaridade com cada partida. Embora a configuração padrão funcione bem para uma grande variedade de dados textuais, como nomes de produtos ou endereços de clientes, a correspondência também pode ser personalizada para domínios ou idiomas específicos. (Tradução Google Tradutor.)

#### 2a Opção - Código VBA

Este código foi testado no Excel VBA e os créditos estão [nesta página](https://superuser.com/questions/437387/comparing-similar-text-strings-in-excel).

```
Public Function Similarity(ByVal String1 As String, _
    ByVal String2 As String, _
    Optional ByRef RetMatch As String, _
    Optional min_match = 1) As Single
Dim b1() As Byte, b2() As Byte
Dim lngLen1 As Long, lngLen2 As Long
Dim lngResult As Long

If UCase(String1) = UCase(String2) Then
    Similarity = 1
Else:
    lngLen1 = Len(String1)
    lngLen2 = Len(String2)
    If (lngLen1 = 0) Or (lngLen2 = 0) Then
        Similarity = 0
    Else:
        b1() = StrConv(UCase(String1), vbFromUnicode)
        b2() = StrConv(UCase(String2), vbFromUnicode)
        lngResult = Similarity_sub(0, lngLen1 - 1, _
        0, lngLen2 - 1, _
        b1, b2, _
        String1, _
        RetMatch, _
        min_match)
        Erase b1
        Erase b2
        If lngLen1 >= lngLen2 Then
            Similarity = lngResult / lngLen1
        Else
            Similarity = lngResult / lngLen2
        End If
    End If
End If

End Function

Private Function Similarity_sub(ByVal start1 As Long, ByVal end1 As Long, _
                                ByVal start2 As Long, ByVal end2 As Long, _
                                ByRef b1() As Byte, ByRef b2() As Byte, _
                                ByVal FirstString As String, _
                                ByRef RetMatch As String, _
                                ByVal min_match As Long, _
                                Optional recur_level As Integer = 0) As Long
    '* CALLED BY: Similarity *(RECURSIVE)

    Dim lngCurr1 As Long, lngCurr2 As Long
    Dim lngMatchAt1 As Long, lngMatchAt2 As Long
    Dim I As Long
    Dim lngLongestMatch As Long, lngLocalLongestMatch As Long
    Dim strRetMatch1 As String, strRetMatch2 As String

    If (start1 > end1) Or (start1 < 0) Or (end1 - start1 + 1 < min_match) _
       Or (start2 > end2) Or (start2 < 0) Or (end2 - start2 + 1 < min_match) Then
        Exit Function                            '(exit if start/end is out of string, or length is too short)
    End If

    For lngCurr1 = start1 To end1
        For lngCurr2 = start2 To end2
            I = 0
            Do Until b1(lngCurr1 + I) <> b2(lngCurr2 + I)
                I = I + 1
                If I > lngLongestMatch Then
                    lngMatchAt1 = lngCurr1
                    lngMatchAt2 = lngCurr2
                    lngLongestMatch = I
                End If
                If (lngCurr1 + I) > end1 Or (lngCurr2 + I) > end2 Then Exit Do
            Loop
        Next lngCurr2
    Next lngCurr1

    If lngLongestMatch < min_match Then Exit Function

    lngLocalLongestMatch = lngLongestMatch
    RetMatch = ""

    lngLongestMatch = lngLongestMatch _
                    + Similarity_sub(start1, lngMatchAt1 - 1, _
                                     start2, lngMatchAt2 - 1, _
                                     b1, b2, _
                                     FirstString, _
                                     strRetMatch1, _
                                     min_match, _
                                     recur_level + 1)
    If strRetMatch1 <> "" Then
        RetMatch = RetMatch & strRetMatch1 & "*"
    Else
        RetMatch = RetMatch & IIf(recur_level = 0 _
                                  And lngLocalLongestMatch > 0 _
                                  And (lngMatchAt1 > 1 Or lngMatchAt2 > 1) _
                                  , "*", "")
    End If


    RetMatch = RetMatch & Mid$(FirstString, lngMatchAt1 + 1, lngLocalLongestMatch)


    lngLongestMatch = lngLongestMatch _
                    + Similarity_sub(lngMatchAt1 + lngLocalLongestMatch, end1, _
                                     lngMatchAt2 + lngLocalLongestMatch, end2, _
                                     b1, b2, _
                                     FirstString, _
                                     strRetMatch2, _
                                     min_match, _
                                     recur_level + 1)

    If strRetMatch2 <> "" Then
        RetMatch = RetMatch & "*" & strRetMatch2
    Else
        RetMatch = RetMatch & IIf(recur_level = 0 _
                                  And lngLocalLongestMatch > 0 _
                                  And ((lngMatchAt1 + lngLocalLongestMatch < end1) _
                                       Or (lngMatchAt2 + lngLocalLongestMatch < end2)) _
                                  , "*", "")
    End If

    Similarity_sub = lngLongestMatch

End Function
```

Que um teste simples é o visto na imagem a seguir:

[image: Teste Similaridade]

Que significa que ambos possuem uma similaridade de 94,1176%.

Esta função (`Similarity`) pode ser utilizada para comparar uma base de dados e a partir de um ponto de ajuste mínimo as duplicatas podem ser encontradas por similaridade em porcentagem. Esta análise pode ser demorada para uma base grande, sendo necessária uma programação de boa qualidade e com ênfase na performance, caso deseje um tempo de processamento melhor.

#### 3a Opção - Distância Levenshtein

Créditos: [sysmod](http://www.sysmod.com/modLevenshtein.bas)

```
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Long

Option Explicit
'Option Base 0 assumed

Sub testLevenshtein()
Dim s1 As String, s2 As String, lTime As Long, i As Long, teste As Long

s1 = "Luiz Carlos Silva"
s2 = "Luis Carlos Silva"

lTime = GetTickCount()

   teste = LevenshteinB(s1, s2)

Debug.Print GetTickCount - lTime; " ms" ' 234  ms
Debug.Print teste
End Sub


'POB: fn with byte array and inline MIN code is 17 times faster
Function LevenshteinB(ByVal string1 As String, ByVal string2 As String) As Long
'http://www.sysmod.com/modLevenshtein.bas
Dim i As Long, j As Long, ByteArray1() As Byte, ByteArray2() As Byte
Dim string1_length As Long
Dim string2_length As Long
Dim distance() As Long
Dim min1 As Long, min2 As Long, min3 As Long
Const UseWSMIN = False

string1_length = Len(string1)
string2_length = Len(string2)
ReDim distance(string1_length, string2_length)
ByteArray1 = string1
ByteArray2 = string2

For i = 0 To string1_length
    distance(i, 0) = i
Next
 
For j = 0 To string2_length
    distance(0, j) = j
Next
 
For i = 1 To string1_length
    For j = 1 To string2_length
        'Unicode, compare both even and odd bytes
        If ByteArray1((i - 1) * 2) = ByteArray2((j - 1) * 2) And _
            ByteArray1((i - 1) * 2 + 1) = ByteArray2((j - 1) * 2 + 1) Then
            distance(i, j) = distance(i - 1, j - 1)
        Else
          If UseWSMIN Then
            distance(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Min _
            (distance(i - 1, j) + 1, _
             distance(i, j - 1) + 1, _
             distance(i - 1, j - 1) + 1)
          Else
            ' spell it out, 50 times faster than worksheetfunction.min
            min1 = distance(i - 1, j) + 1
            min2 = distance(i, j - 1) + 1
            min3 = distance(i - 1, j - 1) + 1
            If min1 <= min2 And min1 <= min3 Then
                distance(i, j) = min1
            ElseIf min2 <= min1 And min2 <= min3 Then
                distance(i, j) = min2
            Else
                distance(i, j) = min3
            End If
          End If
        End If
    Next
Next
 
LevenshteinB = distance(string1_length, string2_length)
 
End Function
```

Que retorna o resultado da imagem:

[image: Resultado]

Neste teste as informações que aparecem são de quantos caracteres são diferentes entre as duas Strings e o tempo para uma comparação que é de menos de 1 ms, para 100 iterações levou 16 ms.

## EDIT:

Um código de exemplo para trabalhar com a função de similaridade:

```
Sub testSimilaridade()
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim Arr() As Variant, NewArr() As Variant
    Dim Names As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim Similaridade As Single, Limite As Single
    Set Names = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Names")
    SheetKiller ("NewNames")
    Set ws = Sheets.Add
    ws.Name = "NewNames"
    LastRow = Names.Cells(Names.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Arr = Names.Range("a2", Names.Cells(LastRow, 1))
    NewArr = Arr
    Limite = 0.9
    
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        If Not i = UBound(Arr) Then x = i + 1
        For k = x To UBound(Arr)
            Similaridade = Similarity(CStr(Arr(i, 1)), CStr(Arr(k, 1)))
            If Similaridade > Limite Then
                NewArr(k, 1) = ""
            End If
        Next k
    Next i

    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        ws.Cells(i, 1) = NewArr(i, 1)
    Next i
    ws.Range("A:A").Sort Key1:=ws.Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End Sub

Public Function SheetKiller(Name As String)
    Dim s As Worksheet, t As String
    Dim i As Long, k As Long
    k = Sheets.Count

    For i = k To 1 Step -1
        t = Sheets(i).Name
        If t = Name Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Sheets(i).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

#### Resultados:

Com estes dados de exemplo:

[image: Exemplo]

O Resultado é o seguinte:

[image: Resultado]

#### Outro Teste de Resultado

Um teste pode ser feito com a [base de dados "nickname-and-diminutive-names-lookup"](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/carltonnorthern/nickname-and-diminutive-names-lookup/master/names.csv), que com 2266 entradas, a saída foi de 1509 registros. Realizando em menos de 60 segundos.

Para realizar o parse dos dados, fazer um copiar e colar dos [dados raw](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/carltonnorthern/nickname-and-diminutive-names-lookup/master/names.csv) na célula A2. E depois rodar o seguinte código:

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet, source As Worksheet
Dim LastRowA As Long, LastRowB As Long, i As Long, k As Long
Dim strCell As String
SheetKiller ("Names")
Set ws = Sheets.Add
ws.Name = "Names"
Set source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1")

LastRowA = source.Cells(source.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastRowA
    strCell = CStr(source.Cells(i, 1))
    Count = Len(strCell) - Len(Replace(strCell, ",", ""))
    For k = 1 To Count
        LastRowB = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ws.Cells(LastRowB + 1, 1) = EXTRACTELEMENT(strCell, k, ",")
    Next k
Next i
End Sub

Function EXTRACTELEMENT(Txt As String, n, Separator As String) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    EXTRACTELEMENT = Split(Application.Trim(Mid(Txt, 1)), Separator)(n - 1)
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    ' error handling code
    EXTRACTELEMENT = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Daniel, muito obrigado pela ajuda, achei bastante interessante a solução do similarity, porém fiquei com uma dúvida, este código compara uma célula com a outra, no caso que tenho, todos os registros estão na mesma coluna "Nome do cidadão", neste caso eu teria que fazer um laço para bater cada célula com as outras milhões de linhas e em seguida "descer" uma célula e bater novamente com as outras milhões e seguir isto até a ultima linha? O que gostaria de fazer é tirar os registros com mais de 90% de similaridade.

Comment: @BrunoS. É um código um pouco mais avançado e que utiliza arrays para ser mais rápido, editei com um exemplo.